# How can i insert a Row using + symbol in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to insert a row by clicking on + symbol which i have it on one of my cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Parent.Value = "+" Then
        Insert.Row
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, did you try it? What's the result of the code above? Replacing `Insert.Row` with `Target.Parent.EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: `Rows(Target.Parent.Row).Insert`

Comment: I'm curious why you have it in a WorksheetFollowHyperlink macro.

Comment: You could create a small Command Button, write a Sub to insert a row below activecell, add Select_Change event for the worksheet to re-position and/or make visible to that button. This make more interactive. Be sure to only do when `Target.Cells.Count = 0` and on the range that you want it to show.

Comment: @JohnMuggins Cause I thought I have to use WorksheetFollowHyperlink method for inserting a row using + symbol. is there any other way, all I want to do just click on + and insert a row. I never did it that way

Comment: @PatricK Can't use Button, i have to use + sign

Comment: insert a row below the link? `If Target.TextToDisplay = "+" Then Target.Range.Rows(2).EntireRow.Insert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are to add a row below the Hyperlink (below in Worksheet module):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Parent.Value = "+" Then Rows(Target.Parent.Row + 1).Insert
End Sub
```

The thing is, do you have to create another Hyperlink to this new row? This is a short sighted design as you have [a restriction of 66,530 hyperlinks per worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Curious why a command button not an option?

Answer (score 1):

That is new to me.  Do you have a hyperlkink assigned to the "+" sign?  The followhyperlink macro won't work unless you have a hyperlink in that cell.

The following will work with any text cell, you can use plus sign or "Add Row", or any text you want.  Then if that cell is selected then it will add a new row below.  If you want to be sure you don't select the cell by accident you could use "Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)" instead, which would force you to double click the "+" sign to add a row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "+" Then
        Rows(Target.Row + 1).Insert
        Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = "+"
        Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

or to be safe with a double-click

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Value = "+" Then
    Rows(Target.Row + 1).Insert
    Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = "+"
    Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this code is not working... and i have this to add hyperlink to + symbol.....  If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(1, 1), _
             Address:=strString
     End If

Comment: So yes, you do have a hyperlink assigned to the "+" sign.  In that case the answer @PatricK gave you should work.  Just modify it to add your link to the new row.

Comment: what you mean by add my link to the new row.. It is not working